# C++ Format String Macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, string-formatting, compiler-warnings

I have a function that formats a string:

```
template<typename ... Args>
inline std::string format(const std::string & format, Args ... args)
{
    std::size_t size = MINIGINE_FORMAT_PRINTF(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ...) + 1; // +1 for NULL terminated
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf( new char[ size ] );
    MINIGINE_FORMAT_PRINTF(buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args ...);
    return std::string(buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1); // -1 we don't want NULL terminated
}
```

The problem is that when I call this function:

```
format("%d", "");
```

the warning is shown in the templated function, not at the call site.

Is it possible to show the format warning in the call site, not in templated function?

Comment: Your code sheds no light on what you mean by `the warning is shown in the templated function, not at the call site`. [mcve] needed.

Comment: Warning is generated inside format function, when calling sprintf. The error should be shown at call site - aka when calling the format function. When I get warning inside format() function and the function has 100 callers, it is very hard to track down where the error is originating from.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution that fixes my problem.
If compiler generates a warning for the format, the warning is shown at the line that the Macro is invoked.

I have tested both templated format function and the Macro below at:
https://godbolt.org/
and they both seemed to generate identical code when templated function's format argument is const char* instead of std::string

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <memory>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define MINIGINE_FORMAT_PRINTF _snprintf
#else
    #define MINIGINE_FORMAT_PRINTF snprintf
#endif

#define MINIGINE_FORMAT(format, ...) \
/*Capture everything by reference*/[&] /*No arguments*/() \
{ \
    std::size_t size = MINIGINE_FORMAT_PRINTF(nullptr, 0, format, __VA_ARGS__) + 1; \
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf( new char[ size ] ); \
    MINIGINE_FORMAT_PRINTF(buf.get(), size, format, __VA_ARGS__); \
    return std::string(buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1); \
} /*Call the lambda*/()
```

Comment: Meta programming with macro in C++? Your are sure about that?

Comment: Do you have any other solutions to the problem?

Comment: Your question is a little short in details for me sorry. But I don't really get it, if it's really the answer that you was searching why don't accept it? And if not, why don't have edit your post?

Comment: Can you write a wrapper for sprintf that shows format warnings in the call site of the wrapper and not in the wrapper itself?

Comment: I think that's not possible. You may be able to duplicate the warning at the place you want if you reproduce the check of sprintf. But not remove it. You want to change how compilers work. If you want to check assert in automatic way, I'll say used some unit test framework like googletest. May be a little overkill for this case but still better and more portable that trying to control the message of the compiler.

Comment: Not a good thing from my point of view. Modify you code to easily do code review is a thing that should be in unit test. Use macro to change the compiler output is a broken way to do things. Well if it's better for you go for it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to show the format warning in the call site, not in templated function?

Yes and you can do this without macros (almost) using `constexpr` format string checks. For example:

```
template <typename S, typename... Args>
inline std::string format(const S &fmt, const Args &... args) {
  constexpr bool is_valid = check_format_string<Args...>(fmt); 
  // Do formatting.
}
```

where `check_format_string` is a `constexpr` function that parses and checks the format string and `S` is a [compile-time format string](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2017/05/26/constexpr-function-parameters/).

This technique is used in the [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which implements Python-like formatting:

```
// test.cc
#define FMT_STRING_ALIAS 1
#include <fmt/format.h>
std::string s = format(fmt("{2}"), 42);
```

Compile and observe the expected error at the call site:

```
$ c++ -Iinclude -std=c++14 test.cc
...
test.cc:4:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fmt::v5::format<S, int>' requested here
std::string s = format(fmt("{2}"), 42);
                ^
include/fmt/core.h:778:19: note: non-constexpr function 'on_error' cannot be used in a constant expression
    ErrorHandler::on_error(message);
                  ^
include/fmt/format.h:2226:16: note: in call to '&checker.context_->on_error(&"argument index out of range"[0])'
      context_.on_error("argument index out of range");
               ^
```

You still need a macro to build a compile-time string, but this will be unnecessary in C++20.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt}.